# Wants numeric data from varchar2 datatype column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `Product` with a varchar2 datatype of column name `Value`, in this column values are stored as

```
All,10:23,0.84522,1.245,10:54:68,
All,1:22:00,0.245,45:12:00
```

etc.

We have to extract all the floating values like (0.84522,1.245,0.245) and ones that ends with ":00" like (1:22:00,45:12:00).

I have following query, but it doesn't seems to work; it gives me all the values except characters.

```
select * from Product where Values BETWEEN to_char (0) and to_char (2);
```

Comment: send your data as a table please.data of "value" field is confusing for me.

Comment: Columns are designed to hold discreet values.  When you put lists into a single column, it makes life hard.  Hard for you, and hard for the DBMS.  Redesign your schema.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for your opinion, I know that, but there are some situation where you have to deal with these kind of things. If you have any suggestion please share with me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work

```
select *
FROM  Product 
WHERE  
(Value LIKE '%:00' AND Value<>  'ALL') AND (Value BETWEEN  to_NUMBER (0) and to_NUMBER (2))
```

Comment: you need to use to number in case comparison with range of numbers because the values may vary depend on character value

Comment: Hi, when i execute this query, it gave me no results, the I edited it and included only the to_Number And part, it gave me error, invalid number. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select *
  from (select distinct regexp_substr(t.value, '[^,]+', 1, level) phrase
          from Product t
        connect by regexp_substr(t.value, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null) ph
 where regexp_like(ph.phrase, '(\d+\.\d+)|(.+:00)')
```

The regular expression in the where clause may need some tunning

What it does is-

1. seperates all phrases (the inner query)
2. selects only those that matches your criteria

---

**UPDATE**
If you suffer from performance you can try a different approach:

```
create or replace type phrase_typ is object
(
  phrase varchar2(100)
)
;
/
create or replace type phrase_tab as table of phrase_typ;
/
create or replace function split_string(del in varchar2) return phrase_tab
  pipelined is

  phrase  varchar2(1000);
  str_t   varchar2(1000);
  v_del_i number;

  cursor c is with t as
    select value from product;

begin

  for r in c loop
    str_t := r.value;

    while str_t is not null loop

      v_del_i := instr(str_t, del, 1, 1);

      if v_del_i = 0 then
        phrase := str_t;
        str_t  := '';
      else
        phrase := substr(str_t, 1, v_del_i - 1);
        str_t  := substr(str_t, v_del_i + 1);
      end if;

      if regexp_like(phrase, '(\d+\.\d+)|(.+:00)') then
        pipe row(phrase_typ(phrase));
      end if;

    end loop;

  end loop;

  return;
end split_string;
/
```

Now your query should look like this:

```
select * from table(split_string(','))
```

Comment: hello, this query is not executing, it is going on loading with no results :(

Comment: do you mean it takes a lot of time ? if so, how many records do you have ?

Comment: Well the `connect by` with the regexp_substr is a little heavy. Added a different solution, using a `piplined function`